# Excel VBA for Mac won't start

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I'm trying to use VBA on Mac Excel 2011, but nothing seems to be responding. When I click on the 'Editor' button, a blank window that says 'Project' appears, in which I can do nothing. If I hit macros, a window comes up allowing me to input a name and hit create, but that is all and nothing happens after I hit create. I am able to place things like buttons, but I am unable to assign any VBA macros to them. How do I go about getting started on VBA or fixing this problem? Do I need to set up a workspace or something?

Comment: In edit, all of the options are grayed out. When I hit record, after hitting OK, a dialog opens up saying 'Unable to Record'

Comment: It was a miss-install because of Migrator, Thanks!